# How to create dialog overlay of activity, while user login to facebook?

Tags: android

I am using this code to allow the user to log in to facebook when the application is opened. Once the user it loged in the application goes to the main menu.

```
public class facebook_social extends Activity implements LoginListener {

private FBLoginManager fbManager;
Intent intentResult;
Bitmap bmImg = null;
URL myFileUrl =null; 
ImageView i;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    intentResult = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainMenu.class);


       //If the sdk version is Honeycomb the take off strictMode to allow for network connection in main thread.
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11){
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
    shareFacebook();


}

public void shareFacebook() {
    String permissions[] = { "read_stream", "user_relationship_details",
            "user_religion_politics", "user_work_history",
            "user_relationships", "user_interests", "user_likes",
            "user_location", "user_hometown", "user_education_history",
            "user_activities","offline_access"};

    fbManager = new FBLoginManager(this,R.layout.black,"173174566087561",permissions);


    if (fbManager.existsSavedFacebook()) {
        fbManager.loadFacebook();
    } else {

        fbManager.login();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    fbManager.loginSuccess(data);
}

public void loginFail() {
    fbManager.displayToast("Login failed!");

}

public void logoutSuccess() {
    fbManager.displayToast("Logout success!");
}

public void loginSuccess(Facebook facebook) {

    GraphApi graphApi = new GraphApi(facebook);

    User user = new User();
    try {
        user = graphApi.getMyAccountInfo();
    } catch (EasyFacebookError e) {
        e.toString();
    }

    String pkg = getPackageName();

    intentResult.putExtra(pkg + ".myName", user.getName());
    intentResult.putExtra(pkg + ".myId", user.getId());
    startActivity(intentResult);
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.putExtra("name", user.getName());

}
```

}

As you see here the application gives a black backgroud when at this screen to allow the user to log in. What i want to do is, have the log in over top of the main menu. How would i go about doing this?

Integrating it into the main menu activty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android is based on [stacking Activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html), so that's what you should do. You could use [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) to handle the login Activity and enable your main Activity when a positive result (=succesful login) is returned.

Comment: If you look at the LogInSuceess method. When the login is successful, I am starting the main menu. What i dont want is, that when the user presses the back button at the main menu. It returns to a black background where the login activity occured. I want the back button to take the straight to the main menu or homescreen of their device.

Comment: When starting your app, start the main menu and start the login activity through startActivityForResult. Now when the user presses back, you will receive a cancel on the main menu activity. If so, simply close down the app which will return you to the homescreen.

Comment: It keeps looping when i do startActivtyForResult() it keeps launching Over and Over. Its like its not recognizing the activities been launched successfully/